# Run CloudEndPoints Explorer on Local HTTP

Tags: google-chrome, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm trying to run the Api Explorer in LocalHost But it always show the Error
`The API you are exploring is hosted over HTTP, which can cause problems.`

So I follow the instruction

1. Go to File Explorer then paste this to address bar >> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application   (*or just go to where you can find your chrome.exe*)

   2. Right click chrome.exe > send to > Desktop (Create Shortcut)
   3. Go to your desktop then find the chrome shortcut you've created.
   4. Rename it to ChromeForTesting (this step is optional)
   5. Right click the shortcut, then Click Properties
   6. At the "Target", paste the following at the end of the link

   --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080

so Target should look somewhat similar to this

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080
```

7. Click Ok..
8. During testing close all of your opened google chrome browser. 
   Then double click ChromeForTesting shortcut (the one you've created), when a prompt appears, just click ok..

But After compelting this When I run that shortcut it will give the error 
`you are using unsupported command line flag --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080`

I also try to click load unsafe script but this is also not working.

Here is screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Do you see any error in web inspector?

Comment: @saiyr after click on load unsaved script console show `cb=gapi.loaded_0:193 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F_ah%2Fapi&root=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F_ah%2Fapi#p/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_GB.X-chERKKlX0.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCPslKNSrdZPybtRaq05lOJks1EX8w'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.`